# Two Sum problem but target is within a range

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, hash

I've encountered a problem similar to the old two sum problem but instead of solving for a value, it needs to be within a range, and I'm not sure how to efficiently approach this. Here is a simplified version of my problem:

> Given an array of integers in order of preference, find the first two integers whose sum lies between the range of X and Y s.t. X <= sum <= Y (where X < Y and are known, i.e. arbitrarily X=20 and Y=40).

I've done a brute force approach using a for loop, but I'm unsure if this is the most performant solution. I've considered using a hash table, but I don't know how to apply it.

note: by order of preference I mean, the return the first two integers that fulfill this criteria

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: To clarify, the array is ordered or unordered ?

Comment: I think you need an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). For example, with X=20 and Y=40 and a[0]=10, add the interval [10,30] to the tree, since any array element between 10 and 30 is a match for a[0].

Comment: question is how to implement this.


The array is unordered, sorry about that wording.


will check out an interval tree approach.

Comment: Upon further review, It may be easier than an interval tree, since you can force the intervals to be non-overlapping. For example, given a[0]=10, the corresponding interval is [10,30]. Then if a[1]=5, the interval would be [15,35], but [15,30] is already covered, so the interval for a[1] is [31,35]. That way, you can use the [naive approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Naive_approach), which is to store the intervals in a simple binary search tree.

Comment: How do you define "first two". Say X,Y is (55,65) with array [50,40,21,9,...], do you want the 2nd and 3rd? Or the 1st and 4th?

Comment: Also, how do you weigh the preparation vs execution. Do you have a static array and will hit it with many different ranges, so initial setup may be expensive but can query fast afterwards, or if each time is a new array then you likely only make incremental improvements on brute force

Comment: if X,Y is (55,65) for [50,40,21,9,...], I think either (50, 9) and (40,21) are okay solutions for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The array will be different each time, but the range will stay the same, if that makes sense. So setup can be useful if it improves performance time, but it would have to be new setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the binary search method of resolving the 2 sum problem, and tweak your binary search function to search within a range. Something like this:

```
$arr = [1,2,4,6,8,14,15,17];
print_r(first_sum_in_range($arr, 25, 40));



function first_sum_in_range($array, $min, $max){
    foreach ($array as $k=>$a) {
        $b = binary_search_range($array, $a, $min, $max);
        if ($b !== false) {
            return [$a,$b];
        }
    }
}

function binary_search_range($array, $a, $min, $max) {
   $top = sizeof($array) -1;
   $bot = 0;
   while($top >= $bot) 
   {
      $p = floor(($top + $bot) / 2);
      if ($a+$array[$p] < $min) $bot = $p + 1;
      elseif ($a+$array[$p] > $max) $top = $p - 1;
      else return $array[$p];
   }
   return false;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 17
)
```

Comment: OP specifically mentions *find the first two integers*, that means the order of the elements is important, for binary search to work array has to be in sorted state. But then once you sort you lose the *first two* you will get a result but they are not *first two*. And also you don't need binary search if the array is sorted, it can be solved in `O(n)`

Comment: It's not clear whether the correct answer is `8+17` or `14+15`. It all depends on the precise meaning of the phrase *"the first two integers"*

Comment: You are both right.. also I just realized i'm not sorting the array, but i'm assuming it is sorted (by calling it "binary search")...

Answer (score 0):

Add each element to a tree map with key as element and value as list of indices where that element occurs.

While adding element to tree map check if there is a submap whose keys range from `X - current_element` to `Y - current_element` both inclusive. If you have a submap your answer is `[curr_element, A[first_index_of_submap's value_of_first_key] ]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the brute force method you've already tried, but I think this is the *simplest* way.

Starting with a subset of the first two elements, iterate subsets of increasing size comparing the sum of the value of each element in the subset and the value of the last element. When you find a sum within the range, you're done.

This will find the first pair of numbers within the range based on the definition of "first" being "the pair with the lowest maximum index".

```
function findFirstSumInRange(int $min, int $max, array $values = []): array
{
    for ($b = 1, $n = count($values); $b < $n; $b++) {
        for ($a = 0; $a < $b; $a++) {
            if ($min <= ($sum = $values[$a] + $values[$b]) && $sum <= $max) {
                return [$values[$a], $values[$b]];
                // or return [$a => $values[$a], $b => $values[$b]]; if you need the keys as well
            }
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

You can make it faster by skipping any values that are already greater than the upper limit of the range.

```
function findFirstSumInRangeB(int $min, int $max, array $values = []): array
{
    for ($b = 1, $n = count($values); $b < $n; $b++) {
        if ($values[$b] < $max) { // else these sums will all be > the range because one addend is
            for ($a = 0; $a < $b; $a++) {
                if ($values[$a] < $max && $min <= ($sum = $values[$a] + $values[$b]) && $sum <= $max) {
                    return [$a => $values[$a], $b => $values[$b]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

Regarding "the most performant solution", I'd prefer to go for simplicity rather than optimizing for performance unless the performance is causing problems. Just my opinion.